# Debian still using UTC

Tags: debian, time, utc

/etc/localtime is a symlink to Budpaest
/etc/timezone is Budapest

```
root@server:~# cat /etc/adjtime 
LOCAL

root@server:~# date
Sun Aug  6 06:58:42 UTC 2017
```

So all my crons using UTC, how can I use local time?

Answer (score 0):

You actually should have all your time in UTC and then only /etc/localtime linked to particular timezone. Or you could run NTP client.

So what I would suggest are this steps:

- remove /etc/localtime link
- Adjust your systemtime to UTC via date command.
- Use hwclock --systohc to set the system clock to UTC as well
- Now use the tz-select or just do the ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/CET /etc/localtime
- Also you could consider installing some of the ntp clients or ntpd too on that way you will always have correct date and time outputs.

Comment: no problem you are welcome that is proper way to setup time on Unix and Linux systems.